# ggplot2 overlapping causing issues with ridgeplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, seurat

I am creating ridge plots from the Seurat package. This packages utilizes ggplot2. All of my ridge plots look great except for one. I am trying to manually adjust the bandwidth to make this plot look similar to the others but I wind up with two ridge plots overlapping one another.

I can't post an example of the data as the data is a Seurat object and not a standard df. Apologies in advance!

`RidgePlot(object = sc1, features = "FGF2+Heparin")` produces: [image: Ridge plot 1]

When I attempt to change the bandwidth using `+ geom_density_ridges(scale = 2)` I get this: [image]

I am trying to get it to look more similar to this: [image]

Thank you for your help!

***EDIT 02/23/22***

I have made good progress but I am still running into an issue. Ideally, ggplot2 would completely overwrite the previous points.

```
   RidgePlot(sc1, features = "FGF2+Heparin") + geom_density_ridges2(scale = 4, bandwidth = 2) + theme(legend.position = "none") +  xlab("Concentration [AU]") + ylab("Cluster")  +
     scale_fill_manual(
       values = c("#FF3500A0", "#CC9933FF", "#33C04CCF", "#39CCCAAF", "#0000FFA0", "#FF88EEE9")
     )
```

[image]

Comment: The bottom one is log transformed. Maybe that's what you need here. Gene expression data is generally distributed across several orders of magnitude.

Comment: It might look that way but it is actually just a different scale. "Expression Level" is more accurately a dosage so it will vary from growth factor to growth factor.

Comment: If by "completely overwrite" you mean you don't want transparency in your colors, you need to edit your colors. `#FF3500` is an opaque red. Adding `A0` to the end to get `#FF3500A0` (as you have it in your code) adds transparency. If you delete the last 2 characters of all your hex colors, they will be completely opaque.

Comment: What I mean by overwrite is that I change the visual appearance of the data to look more uniform when I add ```bandwidth = 2```. The data is still the same just displayed differently. However, GGplot 2 writes on top of the old plot so I have the old plot overlayed with the new plot. I don't want to see the old plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I indirectly solved the issue I was having by changing the size of the bandwidth and the colors of the plots.

I made some colors translucent so that you can see the peaks behind them. Example: [image]

This code applies to a single plot. `p12 <- RidgePlot(sc1, features = "Y-27632") + geom_density_ridges2(scale = 4, bandwidth = 2.05) + theme(legend.position = "none") +  xlab("Concentration [uM]") + ylab("Cluster") +  scale_fill_manual( values = c("#FF3500A0", "#CC9933FF", "#33C04CCF", "#66CCFF", "#0000FF", "#FF66CC") )`